# Auto-HotKey GUI Button to simulate a keyboard button

Tags: autohotkey

I have a button on a gui Titled "F4," Now when i click that button i want it to simulate the F4 Button on my keyboard.

Is it possible to do it?

This is the button:

```
Gui, Add, Button, x20 y260 w50 h20, F4
```

Comment: What is your OS, what GUI do you refer to, what programming language do you use and what libraries?

Comment: Its Windows 8, the gui AHK that i made. In AHK Language

Comment: In [this forum post](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/60178-gui-button-trigger-sendinput-help/), somebody has the same idea. the problem there: if you press the button, you focus the button the input will be sent to AHK itself. You'll have to find the target window / target control at first, then send your keycode.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from  **[this forum post](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/57707-noactivate-but-clickable/#entry362434)**:

```
Gui, +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop -Caption +E0x08000000
Gui, Font, s22, Arial
Gui, Add, Button, x0 y0 w100 h50 gButton, F4
Gui, Show, x0 y0 w100 h50 NoActivate

; Define a hotkey to show/hide the Gui:

F1::
toggle := !toggle
If (toggle)
    Gui, Cancel
else
    Gui, Show, NoActivate
return

Button:
SendInput, {F4}
return
```

Comment: I'm going to check if this works later. Thank you so much man

Comment: is tehre any way i can toggle this menu on and off the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be how to switch back to the orginal application, so that the data will be sent there, not to AHK itself.

I pasted an example below just for you to look at. At around line 83 you will see that I first check which window is active and then, if required, switch back to the previous window using !{Esc} , before sending the actual data. This was just an exercise which I wrote long ago, to create multiple paste options. I am sure there are lost of things that can be improved, but it will give you some idea as to how you can solve this.

```
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent
; Written by Robert Ilbrink, The Netherlands
Menu, Tray, Icon , Shell32.dll, 247, 1
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
Global Nr := 1
Next=Copy
x:=A_ScreenWidth-250
y:=A_ScreenHeight/2
; ================================== GUI ================================== 
ShowListBox:
Gui, +Resize
Gui, Add, ListBox, h270 w195 vMyListBox gMyListBox, 01 %Array_1%|02 %Array_2%|03 %Array_3%|04 %Array_4%|05 %Array_5%|06 %Array_6%|07 %Array_7%|08 %Array_8%|09 %Array_9%|10 %Array_10%|11 %Array_11%|12 %Array_12%|13 %Array_13%|14 %Array_14%|15 %Array_15%|16 %Array_16%|17 %Array_17%|18 %Array_18%|19 %Array_19%|20 %Array_20%
;Gui, Add, Button, x10  y275 w45 h20, Paste
Gui, Add, Button, x10  y275 w45 h20, Refresh
Gui, Add, Button, x60 y275 w45 h20, Help
Gui, Add, Button, x110 y275 w45 h20, Special
Gui, +AlwaysOnTop
WinGet, State, MinMax, 
If (State = -1)
    Return
Else
    Gui, Show, x%x% y%y%,Clippy CapsLock = %Next%
Return

GuiSize:
  GuiControl, Move, MyListBox, % "w" A_GuiWidth - 20
  GuiControl, Move, MyListBox, % "h" A_GuiHeight - 30
  GuiControl, Move, Refresh, % "y" A_GuiHeight - 25
  GuiControl, Move, Help, % "y" A_GuiHeight - 25
  GuiControl, Move, Special, % "y" A_GuiHeight - 25
return


; ================================== SHORTCUTS ================================== 
;+^1::MySend(Array_1)  ; [Shift]+[Ctrl]+1 pastes item 1
;+^2::MySend(Array_2)  ; [Shift]+[Ctrl]+2 pastes item 2
;+^3::MySend(Array_3)  ; [Shift]+[Ctrl]+3 pastes item 3
;+^4::MySend(Array_4)  ; [Shift]+[Ctrl]+4 pastes item 4
;+^5::MySend(Array_5)  ; [Shift]+[Ctrl]+5 pastes item 5
;+^6::MySend(Array_6)  ; [Shift]+[Ctrl]+6 pastes item 6
;+^7::MySend(Array_7)  ; [Shift]+[Ctrl]+7 pastes item 7
;+^8::MySend(Array_8)  ; [Shift]+[Ctrl]+8 pastes item 8
;+^9::MySend(Array_9)  ; [Shift]+[Ctrl]+9 pastes item 9
;+^0::MySend(Array_10) ; [Shift]+[Ctrl]+0 pastes item 10
;+^q::MySend(Array_11) ; [Shift]+[Ctrl]+q pastes item 11
;+^w::MySend(Array_12) ; [Shift]+[Ctrl]+w pastes item 12
;+^e::MySend(Array_13) ; [Shift]+[Ctrl]+e pastes item 13
;+^r::MySend(Array_14) ; [Shift]+[Ctrl]+r pastes item 14
;+^t::MySend(Array_15) ; [Shift]+[Ctrl]+t pastes item 15
;+^y::MySend(Array_16) ; [Shift]+[Ctrl]+y pastes item 16
;+^u::MySend(Array_17) ; [Shift]+[Ctrl]+u pastes item 17
;+^i::MySend(Array_18) ; [Shift]+[Ctrl]+i pastes item 18
;+^o::MySend(Array_19) ; [Shift]+[Ctrl]+o pastes item 19
;+^p::MySend(Array_20) ; [Shift]+[Ctrl]+p pastes item 20
; ================================== NUMPAD SHORTCUTS ================================== 
#Numpad1::MySend(Array_1)  ; [Win]+1 pastes item 1
#Numpad2::MySend(Array_2)  ; [Win]+2 pastes item 2
#Numpad3::MySend(Array_3)  ; [Win]+3 pastes item 13
#Numpad4::MySend(Array_4)  ; [Win]+4 pastes item 4
#Numpad5::MySend(Array_5)  ; [Win]+5 pastes item 5
#Numpad6::MySend(Array_6)  ; [Win]+6 pastes item 6
#Numpad7::MySend(Array_7)  ; [Win]+7 pastes item 7
#Numpad8::MySend(Array_8)  ; [Win]+8 pastes item 8
#Numpad9::MySend(Array_9)  ; [Win]+9 pastes item 9
#Numpad0::MySend(Array_10)  ; [Win]+0 pastes item 10
+#Numpad1::MySend(Array_11)  ; [Shift]+[Win]+1 pastes item 11
+#Numpad2::MySend(Array_12)  ; [Shift]+[Win]+2 pastes item 12
+#Numpad3::MySend(Array_13)  ; [Shift]+[Win]+3 pastes item 13
+#Numpad4::MySend(Array_14)  ; [Shift]+[Win]+4 pastes item 14
+#Numpad5::MySend(Array_15)  ; [Shift]+[Win]+5 pastes item 15
+#Numpad6::MySend(Array_16)  ; [Shift]+[Win]+6 pastes item 16
+#Numpad7::MySend(Array_17)  ; [Shift]+[Win]+7 pastes item 17
+#Numpad8::MySend(Array_18)  ; [Shift]+[Win]+8 pastes item 18
+#Numpad9::MySend(Array_19)  ; [Shift]+[Win]+9 pastes item 19
+#Numpad0::MySend(Array_20)  ; [Shift]+[Win]+0 pastes item 20
; ================================== SEND FUNCTION ================================== 
MySend(Item)
{
    ClipBoard = %Item%
    IfWinActive, MultiClipBoard
        Send, !{Esc}
    Sleep, 100
    Send, ^v{Space}
}
; ================================== SINGLE or DOUBLE CLICK ================================== 
MyListBox: ; Single Click (Normal) or Double Click (DoubleClick) to paste data back to other application
if A_GuiControlEvent <> Normal ; Alternatively use "DoubleClick"
    return
GuiControlGet, MyListBox  ; Retrieve the ListBox's current MultiClipBoard.
StringTrimLeft, ClipBoard, MyListBox, 3 
Send, !{Esc}
Sleep, 200
Send, ^v
;Send, {Enter}
;SendInput, %MyListBox%{Tab}
return
; ================================== PASTE BUTTON ================================== 
ButtonPaste: ; Select an item with [Up] / [Down] arrows and press [Paste] to paste data back to other application
Gui, Submit, NoHide
StringTrimLeft, ClipBoard, MyListBox, 3 
Send, !{Esc}
Sleep, 200
Send, ^v
;SendInput, %MyListBox%{Tab}
Return
; ================================== EXIT / CLOSE BUTTONS ================================== 
GuiClose:
GuiEscape:
Gui, Destroy
ExitApp
; ================================== REFRESH BUTTON ================================== 
ButtonRefresh:
Gui,+LastFound
WinGetPos,x,y,w,h
Gui, Destroy
GoSub, ShowListBox
Return
; ================================== Copy Into the List ================================== 
Browser_Favorites:: ; [Star] key to copy to clipboard.
!c:: ; [Alt]+c to copy to multiClipboard.
#c:: ; [Win]+c to copy to multiClipboard.
Send, ^c
Sleep, 100
Array_%Nr% := ClipBoard
Nr++
If (Nr >20) ; wrap around after 20 entries
    Nr:=1
WinGet, State, MinMax, MultiClipBoard
If (State = -1)
    Return ; GUI, Show
Gui,+LastFound
WinGetPos,x,y,w,h
Gui, Destroy
GoSub, ShowListBox
Return
; ================================== CLEAR / OPEN / SAVE ================================== 
ButtonSpecial:
SetTimer, ChangeButtonNames, 30 
MsgBox, 4098, Special Action, [Clear]`, Clears all items`n[Open]`, Open a list`n[Save]`, Save current list.
IfMsgBox, Abort ;  ================================== CLEAR ================================== 
{
    MsgBox, 4100,, Are you sure to clear the list?
    IfMsgBox No
        Return
    Nr := 1
    Loop, 20
    {
        Array_%Nr% = 
        Nr++
    }
    Nr := 1
    Gui,+LastFound
    WinGetPos,x,y,w,h
    Gui, Destroy
    GoSub, ShowListBox
    Exit
}
Else ifMsgBox, Retry ;  ================================== OPEN ================================== 
{
    FileSelectFile, SelectedFile, 3, , Open a file, Text Documents (*.txt)
    If SelectedFile =
        Exit
    Else
    {
        Loop, read, %SelectedFile%
        {
            If A_LoopReadLine =
                Break
            Array_%A_Index% := A_LoopReadLine
            If (A_Index > 20)
                Break
            Nr := A_Index + 1
        }
    }

    Gui,+LastFound
    WinGetPos,x,y,w,h
    Gui, Destroy
    GoSub, ShowListBox
    Exit
}
Else ifMsgBox, Ignore ;  ================================== SAVE ================================== 
{
        FileSelectFile, SelectedFile, S, , Save the list as a Text Document, (*.txt)
        StringReplace, SelectedFile, SelectedFile, `.txt, 
        FileDelete, %SelectedFile%.txt
        Loop, 20
        {
            CurrentLine := Array_%A_Index%
            FileAppend, %CurrentLine%`n, %SelectedFile%.txt ; % Array_%A_Index%, doesn't work
        }
}
Exit
; ================================== HELP BUTTON ================================== 
ButtonHelp:
MsgBox, , MultiClipBoard Help, Press [Alt]+c or [Win]+c to copy highlighted data onto the clipboard (TEXT only).`n`nClick on an item to paste it to the last active application.`n`nPress [Refresh] to refresh the screen after items were added while minimized.`n`nPress [Special] to select`n[Clear] to clear the list (after confirmation),`n[Load] to load items from a file or`n[Save] to save current items to a file. `n`n[Shift]+[Ctrl]+[nr] (1...0) will paste item 1...10.`n[Shift]+[Ctrl]+[letter] (qwertyuiop) will paste item 11...20.
; ================================== RENAME STANDARD MSGBOX BUTTONS FOR SPECIAL MENU ================================== 
ChangeButtonNames: 
IfWinNotExist, Special Action
    return  ; Keep trying.
SetTimer, ChangeButtonNames, off 
WinActivate 
ControlSetText, Button1, &Clear 
ControlSetText, Button2, &Open
ControlSetText, Button3, &Save 
return

; ================================== ToggleCopy ================================== 
CapsLock::
Send %  "{CTRL DOWN}" (!paste ? "c" : "v") "{CTRL UP}"
;SoundBeep, % (!paste ? "300" : "3000"), 100
paste := !paste
;SplashTextOn, 150, 20,%WindowTitle%, % (!paste ? "Press " MyKey " to Copy" : "Press " MyKey " to Paste")
;WinMove, %WindowTitle%, , 800, 5
Menu, Tray, Icon , Shell32.dll, % (paste ? "248" : "247"), 1 ; Toggle between Up/Down Arrow in Icon
Next:=(!paste ? " Copy" : " Paste")
Gui,+LastFound
WinGetPos,x,y,w,h
Gui, Destroy
GoSub, ShowListBox
Send, !{Esc}
Return
; ================================== END ==================================
```